# Is position vector a bound vector or free vector or neither?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

We define a bound vector to be a quantity with a defined starting point, magnitude and direction. A free vector has no defined starting point, just magnitude and direction.

So what is a position vector (of a point)? It is defined relative to something else (Origin), so it has a starting point, size and direction like a bound vector. So it  makes sense to call position vector a bound vector. However if the point is moving around (say some physical object), then position vector direction and magnitude is changing - so is it still bound vector?

And if it is neither a free vector nor bound, does this mean position vectors is a "3rd type" of a vector?

Answer (score 3):

The "free"/"bound" terminology doesn't have a precise mathematical meaning, it's just an informal description of how we're thinking about a vector quantity or what we're using it to represent. The vector itself never contains information about a starting point; it's always just a direction with a magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

I've not heard of a bound versus free vector, but based on your given definition,

since a position vector *does* have a *defined* starting point, magnitude and direction,

then it *is* a bound vector.

P.S. While its starting point is defined and fixed, its magnitude and direction are defined and varying.